# setbaseurl dynamically within express openai connect config

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

Unfortunately, I am not able to know the baseurl of my application until it is deployed in a lambda function and the function URL will be created using terraform after the lambda creation so I cannot pass the value into an environment variable to use in my express app,

with that being said, I am trying to set the baseurl in the auth0config block from the request, but it does not seem to work even though it is already set within the setAuth0BaseURL function for some asynchronous reason the value is undefined when passed to the config block, I don't know exactly what should I be changing to be able to get the value

```
  const setAuth0BaseURL = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const baseURL = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}`;
  process.env.AUTH0_BASE_URL = `${baseURL}/callback`;
  next();
};

app.use(setAuth0BaseURL);

if (!process.env.LOCAL) {
const auth0Config = {
  authRequired: true,
  auth0Logout: true,
  baseURL: process.env.AUTH0_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3000",
  clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENTID || "dummyid",
  issuerBaseURL:
    process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL || "http://COMPANY_AUTH0_URL",
  secret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET || "dummysecret",
};
// Mount the auth middleware
app.use(auth(auth0Config));
}
```

SOLUTION

Based on Mirco suggestion this finally worked

```
const setConfig = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) =>
  auth({
    authRequired: true,
    auth0Logout: true,
    baseURL: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}`,
    clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENTID || "dummyid",
    issuerBaseURL:
      process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL || "http://COMPANY_AUTH0_URL",
    secret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET || "dummysecret",
  })(req, res, next);

app.use(setConfig);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the `auth0Config` object before the environment variable is set. Try doin

```
const setConfig = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) =>
    auth({
        authRequired: true,
        auth0Logout: true,
        baseURL: process.env.AUTH0_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3000",
        clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENTID || "dummyid",
        issuerBaseURL:
            process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL || "http://COMPANY_AUTH0_URL",
        secret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET || "dummysecret",
    })(req, res, next);

app.use(setConfig);
```

so that it is created **after** the first middleware has been invoked.

Comment: thanks mate, i have tweaked your suggestion , I have posted the working solution